# Why does setMouseDown(false) can't interlock callback Function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use MouseDown = true in `fastCount()`

I'm not sure how setState is updated in React-hooks.

MouseDown state doesn't update in FastCount function.

```
function action(fastCount){
    setMouseDown(true);

    setTimeout(()=> fastCount(),2000);

  }




  const fastCount = ()  =>{
    console.log(`fastCount에서 실행 : ${mouseDown}`);

      if(mouseDown){
       setInterval(()=>
        {
            setNumber(number => number+1)

          console.log(`fastCount실행됨`)}, 100);
        }




  }



  return (  
    <>
      <div>{number}</div>
        <button onMouseDown={()=>action(fastCount)}  onMouseUp={plus}>+</button>
        <button onMouseDown={minus}>-</button>
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is the state updates in react are asynchronous. You can update the `mouseDown` on its' own, and detect the `mouseDown` changes using a hook such as `useEffect`.